# handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent: in AppDelegate obscured by KVO?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

i'm seeing a weird issue trying to add custom URL support to my Mac app. i've defined the URL(s) in Info.plist, and when i navigate to them my app gets launched (or, if running, activated), but then, regardless of whether my app delegate implements handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent: or not, i see a couple of the following messages in the debug output:

```
+[NSKVONotifying_MyAppDelegate handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1d096e0
```

Apparently, NSKVONotifying_MyAppDelegate is a wrapper created by KVO for my real delegate (called MyAppDelegate), and that seems to obscure my implementation of handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:, which never gets called. AFAICT, nothing in my app uses KVO on the delegate, and i'm running out of ideas as to what could be causing this.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the KVO thing was a red herring. the method needs to be static, as careful reading of the error message (or docs) would have made clear, while i had an instance method (as one would expect, for delegate methods? weird API design choice).